# Escaping from commented out block

Tags: c++, comments

While this problem can apply to other languages I am looking for solutions that can apply to C++ language.

The problem is, when we comment a block like:

```
void doStuff() {

cout<<"doing stuff";
/*start();
cout<<"done";*/

}
```

The comment out works completely fine, however what I am wondering is when I want to comment out entire function by:

```
/*void doStuff() {

cout<<"doing stuff";
/*start();
cout<<"done";*/

}*/
```

It obviously doesn't work. The only way that I know to make it work is either:

```
/*void doStuff() {

cout<<"doing stuff";
start();
cout<<"done";

}*/
```

OR

```
/*void doStuff() {

cout<<"doing stuff";
*//*start();
cout<<"done";*//*

}*/
```

I know that there are IDE's that can automatically insert // at each line and then get rid off it but that's not what I am after.
My question is, is there any easier way of escaping from inner commented out blocks?

Comment: There aren't nested comments in C++, but there are // comments. If neither of those is what you're after, your question has no answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with comment grammer.

Use #if 0 #endif to comment out a large portion of code with /* */ inside.